# javascript form validation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Why is this form validation not working?
i do it like this:

```
<form name="myForm" action="save-info.php" method="post" onsubmit="return(validu());">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QrYmh/41/

I am trying to add a validation function to my form but it does not work even when I return directly false. The form is still submitted
What is wrong?

I need to add there some validation logic for my inputs. But I cannot seem to do it.
The js debugger (firefox) says ReferenceError: validu is not defined

Please help

Comment: I don't think you need that `document.ready` wrap, can't you just put the function in head/body within the `script` tag and use it?

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/QrYmh/41/), just remove .ready bit and use pure js.

Comment: Your fiddle is the same with my not-working one. Removing the .ready part I get the same not-working result. Didn't you test it first? http://jsfiddle.net/QrYmh/59/

Comment: Harry, the fiddle is constructed after the original web page, where the function is in script tags in the head region. I only added the .ready wrap, after receiving the "validu is not defined" when I believed that the function was not defined when I was calling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery,  you might aswell use the [`submit()` method](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) available.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrYmh/46/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('vdsdsfsdf');
        //validate and submit.
    });
}
```

Comment: And how do I access the myForm specifically ? Because I have more than one form in my page

Comment: @user1137313: You can always add an `id` to the forms  and call like `$('#id').submit` if you want unique validations for each.

Comment: You can do it as @Harry mentions, or `$("form[name='myForm']")`

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I still have no idea on why the regular way does not work (my first fiddle)

Comment: Yours was the first answer that worked. So I will accept it. However, the other answers work too, so I want to thank all of you for getting involved. You were all great.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to reference a `function` from an `on*` attribute, it has to be defined in the global scope.

With `validu()` currently declared inside of another `function`, the `onsubmit` attribute simply can't reach it.

To make `validu()` global:

1. Remove the `$(document).ready(function () { })` surrounding `function validu()`.

   > [Side note] `.ready()` events aren't really necessary just for `function` declarations. They're most useful when you need to select elements from the `document`:
   >
   > ```
   > function handleSubmit(event) {
   >     // ...
   > }
   >
   > $(document).ready(function () {
   >     $('form[name="myForm"]').submit(handleSubmit);
   > });
   > ```
2. Change the JSFiddle option from `onLoad`, which wraps your code in yet another `function`, to either:

   - `No wrap - in <head>`
   - `No wrap - in <body>`

Or, as karthikr suggested, you can also use [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than the `onsubmit` attribute so the event binding and the `function` can be in the same scope.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function validu() {
        alert('vdsdsfsdf');
        return false;
    }

    $('form[name="myForm"]').submit(validu); // <----
});
```

[Revised Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DKS7J/).

Comment: +1 mate, "global scope" that was the part I wasn't sure about when I posted my comment initially :)

Comment: +1 for your elaborated answer. But the first answer worked too so I had to pick that as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function validu() must be accessible by the html code. In this case it is only accessible within the jquery ready function.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to simply place it outside the ready function in jsfiddle to make it work, since jsfiddle itself places the js code inside a window load function.
So you would have to write like so,

```
<script>function validu()
{
    alert('vdsdsfsdf');
    return false;
}</script>
<form name="myForm" action="save-info.php" method="post" onsubmit="return(validu());">

<div class="container" style="width:700px; margin:0 auto;"> 
<fieldset>
.....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QrYmh/52/

Comment: We can do it in fiddle without the `document.ready` option also. You just have to select the wrap in body/head from the frameworks section.

Comment: +1 for a working code. However, I picked the very first answer that worked. Thank you